# 'Likes' vs 'Upvotes'

Tags: psychology, wording, user-generated-content

When it comes to completely anonymous appreciation of videos. What is better to use: 'Likes' vs 'Upvotes'?

I've read elsewhere that likes seem more personal and there is a network involved. But what if it's completely anonymous and it's just a statistic? With a user base ranging between 10 to 50 years old.

Comment: "Know your audience" comes to mind. Do you want to know if they "like" it or think it is a good fit? For example this site, I might not like your question, but think it is a good question. How do you want me to vote?

Comment: It's not for me to know what they like. It's for other users to see how well a video is doing. Like a sort of indication of the public's view of the video's quality

Comment: If the specific goal is to　rank quality in a vote system, then I would use something that points to that, like the SE network. Emotions play no part in quality and emotional phrases should be left out.

Comment: I think the anonymous aspect to this question makes it significantly different to the question it's marked as a duplicate of. Also this is choice of two simple, positive, voting actions not a generic question.

Answer (score 2):

To "like" something has different connotations to "up-voting" something. They are similar and in many ways overlapping but you should choose the one that suits the mental model you want your users to have of your system.

- Likes tend towards being a property of a user. i.e. a user is
  recording their personal preferences.
- Up-votes tend towards being a property of a content object. i.e a user is adding a vote  to the
  content object.

You could imagine a system that has both. Answering why - in a system with both - a customer would choose to one or the other might help you choose.

As your system is anonymous I'd probably lean towards choosing "Up-vote"

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing quality photoshop-tutorials or videos of cats? :]

I think it all depends on your target audience and adressing them in a way (as researched) appropiate. Next to that I believe it's content related so what do you know about the content of the videos? Are they recreational or educational? If it's recreational you might want to go for informal "likes/pleasing", while educational you might want to go for a formal "upvote/quality" system. If it's both recreational and educational a "like" system would be more appropiate since then you're able to (roughly) cover both pleasing and quality.